# How to detect 0 subtract -128 overflow in 8 bits environment?

Tags: assembly, digits

The question confuses me a long time. How to detect overflow in such situation which 0 subtracts (-128) in
8 bits environment.

In class, my teacher teach me a method
to detect overflow, the method is as below:

[image: method worked]

But it doesn't work in such situation:

[image: method not worked]

Above situation computer can detect overflow. But I don't know how computer does it.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an error in your calculation.
Subtracting two numbers in two's complement is not how you've depicted it in the second image.

The image shows addition, not subtraction, and in subtraction you use *borrow* not *carry*.
The `borrow` is where you've made your mistake.

```
 10000000  (borrow)
  00000000 (0)
- 10000000 (-128)
----------
  10000000 (-128)
```

As you can see the first two bits of the borrow are different hence `1 XOR 0 = 1` yields overflow.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Subtraction) for more information.

**Addendum**

To clarify why your assumption of that an overflow has not occurred, when infact it has, in your addition calculation in the second image, is wrong:

```
 00000000  (carry)
  00000000 (0)
+ 10000000 (-128)
----------
  10000000 (-128)
```

Since `0 + -128 = -128` and `0 XOR 0 = 0` hence no overflow.
In this case the addition doesn't cross the `-128 and 127` boundary.

Let's look at a representation of two's complement with only 4-bits.

[image: Two's complement number circle]

`-128` would be represented by `-8`.
If you go from `0` to `-8` counter-clockwise (for subtraction) you'll see that the boundary (depicted by the red line) is not crossed, hence no overflow.

If we take your first example which would be `7 + 1` and go clockwise (addition) from `7` you'll end up at `-8` and you have crossed the boundary, hence overflowed.

What you thought you did in your second image was `0 + 128`. You went from `0` to `-128` *clockwise* (addition). This crossed the boundary but since `128` cannot be represented in 8-bit two's complement the assumption and calculation was wrong.

You assumed `0 + 128` was the same as `0 - (-128)` which it clearly isn't since as said above `128` cannot be represented in 8-bit two's complement.

Comment: Thank for your answer! I think my subtraction way is wrong. I will try more case~